# Capturing hover end event with delegated on() event handler function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to do something similar to the mouseleave callback that the jQuery `hover()` function has:

Syntax:

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

Example `hover()` code:

```
$( "li" ).hover(
  function() {
    // handles hover event
    $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );
  }, function() {
    // handles mouseout/mouseend event
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
  }
);
```

I have tried attaching 2 callbacks to the `on()` function with no success.

Unfortunately I need to use the `on()` delegated event as my DOM elements I need to target have been added dynamically. Does anyone how I can achieve this?

My jQuery at the moment:

```
$('ul.results').on('hover', 'li', function () {
        // hover stuff here
     }, function() {
        // obviously wrong
     }
});
```

Comment: you mean how to use .on with .hover() and two functions?

Comment: You can pass an object of `event: function` pairs to `on` - [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/5YYPv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain multiple `.on()` like this:

```
$('ul.results').on('mouseenter', 'li', function( event ) {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );
}).on('mouseleave', 'li', function( event ) {
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
});
```

Comment: Cheers, this is most what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If i have to do this then i would do it this way:

```
$('ul.results').on({
   mouseenter : mouseEntr
   mouseleave : mouselve
}, 'li');

function mouseEntr(){
   // mouse enter stuff here
}

function mouselve(){
   // mouse leave stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "someList" ).on('hover', 'li', function() {
    // handles hover event
    $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );
  });
$( "someList" ).on('mouseleave', 'li', function() {
    // handles mouseout/mouseend event
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$( "body" ).on('mouseenter', 'ul.results li', function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );
});

$( "body" ).on('mouseleave', 'ul.results li', function() {
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
});
```